# Meaning of the political phrase "he has bottom"

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

What is origin & meaning of the phrase "he has bottom" or "he lacks bottom"?
This is a phrase used in UK politics a great deal.

Answer (score 4):

[Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/debate/article-2139724/Local-elections-2012-The-price-treating-contempt.html)

> Some claim that he has no heart; others that he lacks ‘bottom’ (that
>   old-fashioned but potent word for depth, roots, grounding, principle).

Comment: The posh word is 'gravitas'.

Comment: I think it may refer to ships, to a ship being lightly freighted and having insufficient bottom (or ballast) to handle well.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it implies -it isn't a precise term- a calmness under fire, a certain presence, consistency and determination. Willie Whitelaw would be my perfect exemplar.

Bill Jones (former professor politics and history)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How does 'having bottom' imply a calmness under fire &c.? What are your examples of?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/421234)